# For me to be able to select all the row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net-2010

For me to be able to select all rows in my datagrid and after i select all the row the next step im going to do is to save all the rows i have selected in other table through database now im using a checkbox to select all the rows i have the code for checking all the checkbox my problem is the saving to save all the rows that ive checked in just one button

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As                   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
Dim countCheckDatas As Integer = 0
If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
    '----------Check if all datagridview columns as checked----------
    For count = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(count).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True Then
            countCheckDatas += 1
        End If
    Next
    If countCheckDatas <> DataGridView1.RowCount Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to check all checkbox ?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Check all") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For DGVCols = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(DGVCols).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True
            Next
        End If
    Else
        If MsgBox("Do you want to uncheck all checkbox ?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Uncheck all") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For DGVCols = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                DataGridView1.Rows(DGVCols).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
            Next
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm... alin ang ma fefetch ung DataGridViewColumnName o yung mga data sa Rows ? bigay ka ng halimbawa ng gusto mo makuha na data...

Comment: lahat po ng data sa row mafefetch for example for kapag nacheck ko na po lahat ng checkbox using po yung binigay nyo na code para macheck all... kapag nacheck na lahat ng row isasave ko naman ngayon lahat ng nacheck na row sa ibang table sa database

or pwede rin pong wag nalang gumamit ng checkbox ang mangyayari naman po basta lahat ng row maseselect ko para po kapag save ko lahat ng laman ng datagrid or i mean lahat ng row sa datagrid masasave ng isang bagsakan lang po

Comment: Or ang pinaka mainpoint mo ay ma save lahat ng data sa DataGridView Papuntang Database ganun ba para naka record ?

Comment: oo parang ganon lahat ng ng row sa data grid masasave sa another database sa isang button lang imbis na isa-isahin sya sa pagsave ang mangyayari isang bagsakan lahat ng row sa datagrid for example my 5 row ako sa datagrid dapat yung limang row na yun masave ng sabay sabay :)

Comment: Hndi naman sya literal na sabay sabay ma sasave, it means na sa isang execution or button click i automatically i sasave na nya lahat ng data sa DataGridView hmmm... medyo mahaba to tyka complicado, baka mabigyan ko lang keo ng tips about dyan kc mahaba at nasasa inyo naka depende kung pano nyo sya iinterpret sa database... gawa ng CheckBox

Comment: wala bang paraan para lang maselect lahat ? kasi everytme na ichechek ko yung isang checkbox sa datagrid nasasave naman pero once na check all ko na lahat di na sya nasasave isa isa lang talaga kasi na nakacheck na lahat ng checkbox

Comment: Gawan mo nalang ng loop para isasave nya isaisa...

Comment: pano? di ko alam yung code :)

Comment: >_< Hndi ko rin sya ma gawa kc hindi ko ma imaging yung itsura...

Comment: pano ko send sayo yung picture?

Comment: Cguro Sa FB pag aaralan ko...

Comment: kung gusto mo kuya send ko sayo yung buong system? sa timeout form ka lang magfocus? ibahin mo nalang yung location ng database sa frmmain at timeout frm?

Comment: Jhen Julia... Pa instruct dito sa ginawa nyo...

Comment: ano pong painstruct ?

Comment: Wala Kc Ung Access Database Nyo Nangungulet ung Connection String...

Comment: andun po sa loob ng bin folder backup yung database nun

Comment: Nakita ko dalawa datagridview nyo, pano nga ulet ung gusto nyo mangyari =D

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jhen i just finish the code, just replace this code into your button to store all the data and display it on a new datagridview...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = True Then
                txtattendance.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
                txtnames.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
                txtsection.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
                txtclasssubject.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
                txttimein.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
                txtinstructorname.Text = DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value
                txtclasstime.Text = DataGridView1.Item(8, i).Value
                txttimeout.Text = TimeOfDay
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(Me.txtattendance.Text, Me.txtnames.Text, Me.txtsection.Text, Me.txtclasssubject.Text, Me.txttimein.Text, Me.txttimeout.Text, Me.txtinstructorname.Text, Me.txtclasstime.Text)
                myconnection.Open()
                'Declaration of Variables
                Dim str As String
                Dim vAttendance As String
                Dim vNames As String
                Dim vSection As String
                Dim vClassSubject As String
                Dim vTimeIn As String
                Dim vTimeOut As String
                Dim vInstructorName As String
                Dim vClassTime As String
                vAttendance = txtattendance.Text
                vNames = txtnames.Text
                vSection = txtsection.Text
                vClassSubject = txtclasssubject.Text
                vTimeIn = txttimein.Text
                vTimeOut = txttimeout.Text
                vInstructorName = txtinstructorname.Text
                vClassTime = txtclasstime.Text
                str = "Insert into DATA ([Attendance],[Names],[Section],[ClassSubject],[TimeIn],[TimeOut],[InstructorName],[ClassTime]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance", vAttendance)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", vNames)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", vSection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassSubject", vClassSubject)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn", vTimeIn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOut", vTimeOut)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstructorName", vInstructorName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassTime", vClassTime)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                myconnection.Close()
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("You Just Had Time Out , On Your Class!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "oledb Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

And Also Change The DataGridView1 Code To This...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim countCheckDatas As Integer = 0
    If e.RowIndex = -1 And e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        '----------Check if all datagridview columns as checked----------
        For count = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If DataGridView1.Rows(count).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True Then
                countCheckDatas += 1
            End If
        Next
        If countCheckDatas <> DataGridView1.RowCount Then
            If MsgBox("Do you want to check all checkbox ?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Check all") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                For DGVCols = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(DGVCols).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True
                Next
            End If
        Else
            If MsgBox("Do you want to uncheck all checkbox ?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Uncheck all") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                For DGVCols = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(DGVCols).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

one more thing,

I Saw the Connection String to the MS access but the location is not valid, the MS Access DB is located in your Project folder...

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
'DataFile = "E:\Mytime\TIMEandOUT\TIMEandOUT\bin\Debug\BackUp\Testing.accdb"
DataFile = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\testing.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Best Regards,